# Deploying test and production branches of a git repository on two separate subdomains using a script

Tags: bash, deployment, git-flow

I am currently working on a **Linux bash script to deploy** a specified branch of my git project on my website : **the develop branch to a test subdomain and the main branch to the main domain**.

To do so, I ask for a user input (the branch name) and **execute my set of commands** to deploy on the right subdomain. The only problem I have is that, **these operations involve moving certain parts of the project** and so, I don't really see how I could deploy the two versions. To me, the two options are :

1. Have two repositories to be able to use the two branches separately. This would work fine. BUT, that means I will use double the amount of space which doesn't seem right. (and my project is quite big)
2. Find a way to deploy two branches of one same repository on two different subdomains independently. Meaning that updating one doesn't update the other.

How could I use one repository from which I deploy two branches on two different subdomains ? Is it even possible ?

I thought that I could just switch to the choosed branch and then update but that changes the project for both versions, which seems logical now since the whole project is accessed.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cyrus, but, unfortunately I don't even know what to try, I feel like I'm missing a whole concept that my research hasn't been able to shed light on... Moreover, the only thing I could test out is the first option, which is what I want to avoid doing. Perhaps you could help me as to what you would have expected me to try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I wanted to achieve is impossible. So, have two branches of a same repo running on two separate domains, I downloaded the project twice and have a script to deploy the branch I want...